# iPhone with Windows shared folder

Tags: objective-c, shared-directory

I've searched for 3 days for an simple idea that can help me to get an solution for my problem.
Most of the possible solution I found out in this forum, but none of them really helped me. (maybe I didn't hit the right keywords)

My scenario is:

- I have an application based on JAVA which is integrated with a mySQL database (The application is ready and working)
- I'm trying to create an application for iPhone that would do one of the following:

  - 1 - populate my mySQL database directly or;
  - 2 - Send a txt file with to an Windows shared folder
    For this second option, I have already created a job in JAVA to check the folder, read the new files inserted and process its contents in mySQL database.

As I know Objective-C doesn't have native support to mySQL, I assumed the second option is the best one, so here is my question:

How it is possible to upload text files to a local shared folder? I tried NSFIleManager, but I didn't found any solution to authenticate my user and password to log in into the shared folder.

PS: My iPhone application will be on hand only, it will just upload files, download is not necessary.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: There aren't native iOS APIs to write to a Windows Shared Folder (some people have released libraries...). Neither of those two options sound particularly good good. It would likely be far easier to write a small service that runs on the system, that the iPhone app can connect to and send the data, which will then populate the MySQL tables.